# Hadoop multinode cluster, root permission denied

Tags: hadoop, ssh, root

We are trying to make a multinode cluster on hadoop, but after running start-dfs.sh file on master it is asking for root@slave and root@master's password and then shows password denied. ***ssh slave*** and ***ssh master*** from master are running properly. How to proceed now ?
[screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgPuJ.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell does this command prompt for password..? ssh user@host

Comment: Clear ~/.ssh folder and ssh-copy-id with `hduser@master`.

Answer (score 0):

Start your cluster as hduser `$ bin/start-dfs.sh`. Because, you must have created your ssh public keys with `hduser` only. This user is supposed to be there in your slave machines also. Moreover It is not advisable to use `root`.

Answer (score 0):

1. chmod 700 .ssh
2. chmod 600 .ssh/* use your hduser account 
   that will be fine